# Unity sprites don't render properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I recently came across a problem I can't solve which involves not being able to draw my sprites properly. I have tried a lot of different things and couldn't find any solution.

Here is how the image should look like in unity:
[image]

And here is how it actually looks like:
[image]

If someone could tell me how to fix this, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the top image is a screenshot of your image manipulation program, many of which use the chequerboard pattern to mean transparency. As such, the image you have exported is a gradient going from  almost solid white at the bottom to transparent at the top. This is why the image appears as such in Unity.

Also, if you're wondering why the image appears as though it has bands of different colours, this is due to a problem called [colour banding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding). This can be fixed by using a technique called [Dither](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) (which adds some noise to the image), but how you do so will depend on which image manipulation program you are using.

Comment: So whats the problem with this pattern? Whats wrong with gradients and do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to the colour banding that's occurring in Unity, or the way that the image isn't opaque?

Comment: I want to know how can I fix the image appearance. I want the image to look exactly like in the manipulation program.

Comment: In which case you'll need to create a chequerboard pattern in your image manipulation program, and then add your gradient on top of it.